# Does Django have the capability of sharing a field value between a pair of users such as a symmetric key?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework, encryption-symmetric

I want a user to be able to take plaintext and paste it into a form to submit using a symmetric key and then receive the ciphertext. Then using the ciphertext another user who shares the symmetric key can use that key to decrypt that ciphertext.

I'm new to Django and believe I need to setup a user model and use that model somehow to solve the problem but I'm not sure how and cannot find any information to help. I believe I need a special model because that's how you store and retrieve user information but I could be wrong.

```
*from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser*

*from django.db import models*

*class CustomUser(AbstractUser):*

*age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)*

*key = models.??????*
```

**The actual results should be as follows:**
A user logs in and chooses from a list of users that they have "befriended" so to speak where **they both share the same symmetric key(<--the topic of question)**. That user then takes plaintext such as a sentence or paragraph and pastes this information into an HTML form where they can click submit. Upon submission the plaintext is encrypted using the key respective of the intended recipient. Then that information runs through a encryption algorithm and returns ciphertext. That user then takes that ciphertext and emails (for example) it to the intended friend. That friend can then login to the same application used by the sender and choose that sender as the message's origin. Then the recipient user will take the ciphertext, again paste it into a HTML form where when they click submit the application will use the message's original symmetric key to decrypt the garbled text into plaintext.

Comment: It's important to clarify the requirements for your problem. Do you want admins to be able to decrypt messages being sent? Do all messages have only 1 intended recipient that should be able to view the message?

Comment: Only the user pairs respectively can decrypt and encrypt the information. Admins shouldn't have the ability to use the symmetric keys at all. So I guess the keys will be hashed. But the idea is the multiple users can sign up and connect with another user. However, symmetric keys between two users can only be used between those two users. For example if Bob, Susan, and Mike sign up. And Bob connected with Mike and Susan. If Bob wants to send a message to Susan then Bob and Susan will share a key that can only be used between the two.

Comment: So if Bob accidentally sent the message intended for Susan but to Mike. The symmetric key shared between Mike and Bob won't be able to decrypt the message that was intended for Susan.

Comment: Hope this helps. I also appreciate the help.